# Who should moderate the chat room about general discussion for OR?

Tags: discussion, chat

When the site was created, a [room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94323) was created automatically (yay!) by the Feeds user. However, of course, **no room owners were appointed**!

Other network moderators can't decide who should moderate a chat room without the community consensus, so I created this post for the community to decide who should be appointed as room owner.

I believe the appropriate way would be to post an answer like this (you can nominate yourself, yes!):

> [image] [image]
>
> I believe double-beep would make a good room owner because they do *beep beep* all the time.

Flairs generated with:

```
![](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/flair/userid.png)
![](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/userid.png)
```

<sub>I don't really know how many Room Owners should be appointed, feel free to also vote for this</sub>

Comment: Opting out, @fbahr [UID:138]-

Comment: For more information about what room owners can do, read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271269/364003

Comment: Using [Site Flair](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/flair/51.png) says little about one's contribution on Meta or Chat. There's no difference between it and what appears directly beneath their posts or on this site's profile. Did you mean to use the [Flair value that shows up in our Chat](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/4485506.png)? - That means that I already see the Flags in our room and other chats on the server. If you come up short staffed I can assist.

Comment: Unfortunately, this not a thing. In a few weeks, Stack Exchange will start the process of appointing your provisional Moderators who will take care of things like this (we're also experimenting a bit with Pro Tem elections). But we do not have a separate team of "chat moderators", and this is not the process by which they would likely be chosen. It is far too soon for this.

Answer (score 2):

Not a nomination, but usually the users who are appointed as room owners are typically the ones who are <strike>appointed</strike> elected moderators of the site the chat is connected to, examples would be Ask Ubuntu General Chat Room, Chat of Things, Class Room, and etc.

So when we get moderators on OR.SE they can appoint themselves as owners. Unless the chat is very active the **semi**-traditional practice of appointing the site moderators as owners will work out fine.

Here is this whole post in English and summarize:

I nominate all the site moderators to be the RO of our main room because that should be all we need **unless we really need more**. It works out fine before and I'm sure it will still work fine up to now.

<sub>Side note, a room owner can be automatically appointed by [Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2), however I believe anyone can cheat that system.</sub>

Comment: Moderators will be elected later - if no RO is appointed, even a mod, then someone can cheat the system to become one, so I fail to see your point. And, also, moderators can't do whatever they want, so I doubt if they are going to appoint themselves without some community consensus.